# Selecting pixels within a circle having a decimal (non integer) radius

Tags: c++

I want to select a pixel within a circle of a certain radius. But the radius is expressed in a decimal form (0.12). What does it mean to have a radius equal to 0.12? And concretely how to pick a pixel within a circle having such a radius?

[image]

Comment: What units is the radius measured in? It doesn't make a lot of sense to have a radius of 0.12 pixels (it would just be the one center pixel). It's probably 0.12 centimeters, or 0.12 ems, or something like that.

Comment: Also what does it mean to 'pick a pixel'? Given a pixel coordinate, do you want to know if it is inside the circle?

Comment: By "to pick a pixel" I meant to randomly choose a pixel inside the circle. The units are not mentioned. The circle has a center C(Cx, Cy), which is a pixel. My guess is, a pixel inside the circle has coordinates P(Px, Py) such that sqrt((Px-Cx)^2+(Py-Cy)^2) < 0.12 (the distance between P and the center C is less than the radius) . That's the most logical way to think about it in my opinion.

Comment: I'm betting the 0.12 is in "uv space" meaning it's 12% of the image size (on each axis).